# How to minimize a function in R with two constraints?

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, mathematical-optimization, minimization

I want to solve a minimization problem with two constraints in R.

Problem: min x^T*H*x 
s.t

(1) e^T*x = 1,

(2) 0 < x_i <= 1 , i=1,..,20.

`H` is a 20x20 Matrix and `e` is vector of ones with length 20

How can I do this? I looked at `optimize`, `optim` and `optimix`, but somehow I don't know how to start.

I started to create my objective function:

```
f<- function(x) {t(x)%*%H%*%x}
```

and constraint (1)

```
g<- function(x) {t(e)*x=1}
```

But I don't know how to formulate constraint (2).

I also don't know which optimization function is suitable for this problem. 
I am thankful for any advice.

In the end I want to receive a vector x with 20 values.

Comment: you may check `lpSolve`

Comment: Just for clarification "^T" should indicate a transpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do with the `CVXR` package.

Note that (1) is the same as `sum(x_i) = 1`, and (2) can be simplified to `x_i > 0` because `sum(x_i) = 1` and `x_i > 0` **=>** `x_i <= 1`.

```
H <- rWishart(1, df = 30, diag(20))[,,1] # a 20x20 symmetric positive matrix

library(CVXR)

# the variable
x <- Variable(20)

# objective 
objective <- Minimize(quad_form(x, H))

# define problem
constraint1 <- sum(x) == 1
constraint2 <- x > 0
problem <- Problem(objective, constraints = list(constraint1, constraint2))

# solve problem
result <- solve(problem)

# results
result$getValue(x) # optimal x
result$value # value of objective at optimal x
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

check the `quadprog` package.
It has a function `solve.QP`to solve the following quadratic programming:

min(-d^T b + 1/2 b^T D b) with the constraints A^T b >= b_0.

In your case D=H*2, d = 0.

Here is how you can construct the matrix A and vector b0 for your problem:

```
Amat <- t(rbind(rep(1, n), diag(1, 20), -diag(1, 20))
b0 <- c(1, rep(0, 20), rep(-1, 20))
```

Then you can run

```
library(quadprog)
solve.QP(Dmat = 2*H, dvec = 0, Amat = Amat, bvec = b0, meq = 1)
```

Note that `meq = 1` indicates that first inequality should be an equality.

If you only want the optimal `x` values then try this:

```
solve.QP(Dmat = 2*H, dvec = 0, Amat = Amat, bvec = b0, meq = 1)$solution
```

Hope this helps.